# Using powershell to duplicate file and change file name with datetime

Tags: powershell

I would like to move a file to another folder to become two files with different file name with datetime, prefix and specific characters. Then remove the original file after completion.

For example, I have `c:\source\aaa.pdf` and want it to be duplicated to

- `c:\destination\12345_TPE_aaa_20180614151500.pdf`
- `c:\destination\12345_TXG_aaa_20180614151500.pdf`
- then delete `c:\source\aaa.pdf`.

Now I was stuck at even only file name changing, I tried

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | rename-item -newname ('12345'+'_TPE'+$_.Name+'_'+(Get-Date -f yyyymmddhhmmss)+'.pdf')
```

but the original name will not be included.

Can any expert please help?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather easy fix, actually: `$_` only exists in *scriptblocks* that are arguments to cmdlets. You've been using normal parentheses, which are not a scriptblock. Just change it as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | rename-item -newname {'12345'+'_TPE'+$_.Basename+'_'+(Get-Date -f yyyyMMddhHHmmss)+'.pdf'}
```

(Also, your date format string is suspect, as you include minutes instead of months there; I've fixed that.)

Or, as a slightly easier to read alternative using a single format string, maybe:

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf |
  Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}_TPE_{1}_{2:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.pdf' -f 12345,$_.Basename,(Get-Date) }
```

Comment: Thanks Joey it works! Can my another part of question be done or there is no such function in Powershell?If not I'm thinking to copy twice to different folder then rename it one by one.

Comment: I'd probably just make two copies and delete the original. Yes, this means that you cannot simply pipe from `Get-ChildItem` directly to `Rename-Item`, but instead you have to use `ForEach-Object`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the other part to your problem -

```
$source = "C:\Source"
$dest = "C:\Destination"
$files = Get-ChildItem *.pdf 
foreach($file in $files)
{
    $filename1 = '12345'+'_TPE_'+$file.Basename+'_'+(Get-Date -f yyyymmddhhmmss)+'.pdf'
    $filename2 = '12345'+'_TXG_'+$file.Basename+'_'+(Get-Date -f yyyymmddhhmmss)+'.pdf'
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $dest -PassThru | Rename-Item -NewName $filename1
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $dest -PassThru | Rename-Item -NewName $filename2
    Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force
}
```

Could have made that smaller with continuous pipes, but the present one is easier to understand and looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the files you're getting from `Get-ChildItem` using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object).

Then copy the file to each destination as the new name. This saves copying then renaming the file.

Then lastly delete the original file from source.

```
$source = "c:\source"
$destination = "C:\destination"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddhHHmmss
    Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination "$destination\12345_TPE_$($_.Basename)_$date.pdf"
    Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination "$destination\12345_TXG_$($_.Basename)_$date.pdf"
    Remove-Item -Path $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the way Joey took it modular, to extend on this

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\14\SO_50852052.ps1
$Src = 'C:\Source'
$Dst = 'c:\destination'
$Prefix = '12345'
$Types = 'TPE','TPG'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Src *.pdf | ForEach-Object {
    ForEach ($Type in $Types){
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination (Join-Path $Dst (
        "{0}_{1}_{2}_{3:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.pdf" -f $Prefix,$Type,$_.Basename,(Get-Date)))
    }
    $_ | Remove-Item 
}
```